# Como reajustar el formulario bootstrap al ocultar una columna

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox, flex

tengo un formulario que tiene varias filas, cada fila con varias columnas, pero de esas columnas puede que en algún momento alguna no se vaya a mostrar por algún motivo, quiere decir que se oculta la columna, pero al hacer esto queda un espacio vacio, hay alguna forma de hacer que cuando se oculte una columna se reajuste el formulario?.

o sea me explico cuando oculte una columna, la columna que le sigue en la fila de atras suba y se reajuste el formulario.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>

    <div class="row">  
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">        
            <div class="textlabel" data-label="Campo1">           
               <div class="input-group">   
                   <input type="text" 
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">  
            <div class="textlabel" data-label="Campo2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" 
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="row">     
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="textlabel" data-label="Campo3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" 
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="textlabel" data-label="Campo4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" 
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Comment: podrias añadir el codigo para poder ayudarte seria de gran ayuda

Comment: ya subi el codigo del form, la idea es que se oculte o elimine algun campo de arriba los demas suban y se reajuste el form de tal forma que no me queden espacios vacios en el medio del form

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo columnas con filas y viceversa. Lo que quieres hacer es relativamente fácil, pero cuéntanos ¿cómo estás ocultando los campos que no necesitas? Supongo que con JS, muéstranos por favor esa parte del código

Comment: Tienes tus pares de columnas en filas diferentes, de esa manera no se podría, tendrían que estar en el mismo .row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias intentar con **css flexbox**

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex>input {
  width: 190px;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="flex">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</form>
```